# Why using the "safe" filter in jinja creates nested elements

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a python dictionary called "asides". The values of this dict are html snippets loaded from my database and I want to inject them into a jinja template.

The below is the jinja snippet:

```
<div class="small-3 large-3 columns">
        {% for k in asides.keys() %} 
            <div id={{k}} class="aside">{{asides[k]|safe}}</div>
        {% endfor %}
</div>
```

This creates nested divs. Say my dict has ids 1 and 2, this will do the following:

```
<div class="small-3 large-3 columns">
            <div id=1 class="aside">some html here
            <div id=2 class="aside">some html here
            </div>
            </div>
</div>
</div>
```

If I remove the safe filter, it behaves normally creating non nested divs.

I would like to know why the safe filter does this and how to avoid it (as I don't want nested divs).

---

All right, following the suggestion in the comments I realized where the issue was. I am going to document it here as it's a funny business in my opinion.

So, in app.py (using Flask):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

@app.route('/')
def index():
    d = {'1':'<p>Test 1</p', '2':'<p>Test 2</p>'}
    return render_template('index.html', d=d)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

Note how the html of the first element in d is not correct. The closing p tag is missing a ">".

Then in the template

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            {% for k in d %}
                <div class={{k}}>{{d[k]|safe}}</div>
            {% endfor %}    
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This will nest the second div inside the first div.

I think the question is still open as it would be interesting to know why this happens.

Comment: I cannot duplicate your problem.  I have copied you template verbatim and created a small python script to instantiate the template and render it.  Can you share actual working code that produces the output you're seeing?

Comment: I pushed a temporary git here: https://github.com/kfk/vistula_article. If safe is removed from the index.html filter, it will not nest the divs, otherwise it will.

Comment: Good practice in asking questions on the internet is to reduce your problem to the smallest piece of working code you can that demonstrates your problem. Preferably  I don't have time to scour your entire codebase for the problem.  Also, creating a temporary commit that you intend to delete later makes this post useless for anyone who find it later looking for answers to the same problem.  Please edit your question with actual code that can be run to demonstrate your problem, preferably in under twenty lines or so.

Comment: Are you looking at source itself, or using something like Chrome's web developer tools to see the output? Remember that sometimes tools like Chrome's will show you the HTML as Chrome parsed it (fixing invalid HTML and such) rather than what was actually created.

Comment: @MarkHildreth, I am using Chrome web developer tools. Let me check after work. I will output the html file directly from jinja2 and look at the source.

Answer (score 1):

Your template has an error

```
d = {'1':'<p>Test 1</p', '2':'<p>Test 2</p>'}
```

the first para tag is not properly closed, it should be

```
'1':'<p>Test 1</p>'
```

I had the same issue, with incomplete HTML tags in my input data.

I'm not sure if this is a Jinja bug or not, maybe it could handle it better, or create an error